# jQuery UI dialog - after open always going to botoom of page

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

When I opening a big dialog ( longer than all page ) a webrowser is going to bottom of this dialog, but I want to see a begining of dialog ;-)
Option position with [0,0] and 'top' doesn`t work.

```
 $('#view').dialog( {
    autoOpen : false,
    position: [0,0],
    width : 'auto'
 });
```

This is print screen of my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ILBI.png

Edition:

I did it ;-) jQuery UI Dialog with !BIG DIALOGS! rebember my position of browser and opening dialog in that position ( as u can see in my screen shot ). But before loadidng content and open dialog i put:

```
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

and after scrooling dialog opening on the top of page.

Comment: This sounds like a usability problem; if you're opening a dialog that is larger than your page content, that seems to be the bigger problem.

Comment: I puted a printscreen of my problem. In this case my dialog isnt bigger than page.

Comment: It sounds like you're directly calling the dialog on an actual element of your web page. You should clone the control so that it's not part of the normal page body. AKA `$('#view').clone(true).dialog({})`

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want the dialog to be greater than the height of the window?  If you set maxHeight, you should get a scrollable content region, but the full dialog will be visible on screen.  E.g.,

```
$('#view').dialog({
   autoOpen : false,
   width : 'auto',
   maxHeight: $(window).height() - 100
});
```